# Can Item Level Security be configured to apply to multiple non-admin users?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, permissions, item-level-permissions

I know that in SharePoint, we can enable item Level security and configure it so that each list item can only be viewed and edited by the person who created it (and also by anyone with Full Control permission to the list).

I was curious if this functionality could be extended so that the list item can be viewed **by at least two people** (excluding those with Full Control), i.e. the person who created the list item, and another person whose name would appear in a custom field on that same list item?

The idea is that someone could raise a request (list item) to swap a work shift with another nominated person.  The list item would need to be viewable by the requestor and the nominated person only, and absolutely no one else should be able to see it under any circumstances.

Is this possible using a SharePoint 2013 on-premises list using out of the box features, or in worst case scenario - using SharePoint Designer 2013?

I suspect it is not, but wanted to see if anyone had to solve a similar problem in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

You have to break the item permissions & then grant necessary permissions on list item.

You can achieve this using SharePoint designer 2013 workflow which will run on item creation/update & perform above operations.

Check this documentation for 2013 workflow actions: [Workflow actions quick reference (SharePoint Workflow platform)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/workflow-actions-quick-reference-sharepoint-workflow-platform)

**Additional References**:

1. [Changing Permissions Using SharePoint 2013 Workflow With REST Call - Part One](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/changing-permissions-using-sharepoint-2013-workflow-with-rest-call/)
2. [SharePoint 2013 Workflow: Changing Permissions with REST Calls](https://www.benprins.net/2017/01/03/sharepoint-2013-workflow-changing-permissions-with-rest-calls/)

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much.  Just an additional query - assuming I create a workflow triggered when item is created, is there potentially a small lag time when someone could see the item (who is not meant to)?  That is, between the time when the item is created and when the workflow is actually run?

Comment: Yes, all the users with read & higher permissions on list will be able to see the items if workflow not triggered or failed in between before breaking/removing permissions.